# Python multiprocessing: Process object not callable

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

So, recently, I've been experimenting with the multiprocessing module. I wrote this script to test it:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep

def a(x):
    sleep(x)
    print ("goo")

a = Process(target=a(3))
b = Process(target=a(5))
c = Process(target=a(8))
d = Process(target=a(10))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a.start()
    b.start()
    c.start()
    d.start()
```

However, when I try to run it, it throws this error:

```
goo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andrew Wong\Desktop\Python\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    b = Process(target=a(5))
TypeError: 'Process' object is not callable
```

...And I can't tell what's going on.
Does anyone know what happened, and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass arguments to the function that is ran by a `Process` is done differently - looking at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) it shows:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print 'hello', name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',)) # that's how you should pass arguments
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Or in your case:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep

def a(x):
    sleep(x)
    print ("goo")

e = Process(target=a, args=(3,))
b = Process(target=a, args=(5,))
c = Process(target=a, args=(8,))
d = Process(target=a, args=(10,))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    e.start()
    b.start()
    c.start()
    d.start()
```

**Addition:**
Good catch by Luke (in the comments below) - you're overriding the function `a` with the variable name `a` when doing:

```
a = Process(target=a, args=(3,))
```

You should use a different name.

Comment: This doesn't solve it. It makes the first process run but fails running the other ones, ending up with the same error: TypeError: 'Process' object is not callable. I'm also investigating what caused this issue, since this is how the documentation puts it.

Comment: Beat me to it; quick note on this, there's a naming conflict between `def a(x)` and `a = Process...`.  Renaming the variable or function fixes this and I get it running locally.  @DJanssens the trailing comma in the args tuple is important, it won't run without it.

Comment: Luke! Thanks! I fixed the naming error, and now it works!

Comment: Fixing the naming conflict solves the issue Luke Merret! nice one ;) I suggest someone posts this as a real answer or @alfasin updates his.